# jQuery, getting next div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jQuery code, a number spinner for `<input type="number">` that are made by PHP, so that they all have the same div's.
I wanted to change the jQuery code so that it writes near after each `<input>` the current $price(in PHP) * current value of the input.
And the price is a variable in PHP which is different for each `<input>`.
The problem is that I don't know how to make jQuery change the nearest div, so for now it always gets the first $price in PHP and changes the div of the first `<input>`.

PHP code:

```
<?php foreach ( $addon['options'] as $key => $option ) :
$price         = $option['price'] > 0 ? '' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ) ) . '' : '';
?>

    <input type="number" min="0" max="9" />

    <?php if ( 1 ) : ?>

    <label id="oldprice" style="display:none;"><?php echo wptexturize( $option['label'] ) . ' ' . $price;?></label>

    <label><div id="newprice"></div></label>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(
    function( $ ) {

var $testProp = $('div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)').find('.AddnQty');
if ($testProp && $testProp.prop('type') != 'date') {
  // Quantity buttons
  $('div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)').addClass('buttons_added').append('<input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" class="minus" />');

  // Target quantity inputs on product pages
  $('input.AddnQty:not(.product-quantity input.AddnQty)').each(
    function() {

      var min = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));

      if (min && min > 0 && parseFloat($(this).val()) < min) {
        $(this).val(min);
      }
    }
  );


  $(document).on(
    'click', '.plus, .minus',
    function() {

      // Get values
      var $AddnQty = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('.AddnQty'),
        currentVal = parseFloat($AddnQty.val()),
        max = parseFloat($AddnQty.attr('max')),
        min = parseFloat($AddnQty.attr('min')),



        regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g,

        price = document.getElementById("oldprice").innerHTML,
        oldprice = price.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); }),        


        step = $AddnQty.attr('step');


      // Format values
      if (!currentVal || currentVal === '' || currentVal === 'NaN') currentVal = 0;
      if (max === '' || max === 'NaN') max = '';
      if (min === '' || min === 'NaN') min = 0;
      if (step === 'any' || step === '' || step === undefined || parseFloat(step) === 'NaN') step = 1;

      // Change the value
      if ($(this).is('.plus')) {

        if (max && (max == currentVal || currentVal > max)) {
          $AddnQty.val(max);
        } else {
          $AddnQty.val(currentVal + parseFloat(step));
        }
      } else {

        if (min && (min == currentVal || currentVal < min)) {
          $AddnQty.val(min);
        } else if (currentVal > 0) {
          $AddnQty.val(currentVal - parseFloat(step));
        }
      }



       document.getElementById("newprice").innerHTML = oldprice * parseFloat($AddnQty.val());


      // Trigger change event

      $AddnQty.trigger('change');
    }
  );
}
});
```

So here I get the price as integer of the input from PHP. But it always takes the first div.

```
 regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g,

        price = document.getElementById("oldprice").innerHTML,
        oldprice = price.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); }),
```

And here I change it after multiplying. But it only works with first input.

```
       document.getElementById("newprice").innerHTML = oldprice * parseFloat($AddnQty.val());
```

I know that there should be only 1 id. I did it like this because it easier to explain the problem.
I tried to do it with getElementsByClassName but is there a way to get the current number of `<input>` that is being used right now, so we could use this number to change the right newprice class?

Comment: I think you need to use `jQuery.closest()` function. See doc here: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: You have multiple price labels/divs with the same **id**.  Consider using a class name.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I am currently trying closest+find function but I have an error somewhere. Anyway, I am on the right way